# The Generalized Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics

What is the minimum number of students, each of whom
comes from one of the $50$ states, who must be enrolled in
a university to guarantee that there are at least $100$ who
come from the same state?
Solving the above question by using "The Generalized Pigeonhole Principle"
which state that " If $N$
objects are placed into $k$ boxes, then there is at least 
one box containing at least $⌈N/k⌉$ objects."
putting the above concept i got  $⌈N/50⌉\geq100$..
how to solve ahead..?? I am getting $N=5000$ but answer is given $4951$..!!please help

Comment: Note that $\lceil x\rceil \geq 100$ is the same as $x>99$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inequality $\lceil N/50\rceil\ge 100$ is correct. When $N=4951$, we have $N/50=99.02$, so $\lceil N/50\rceil=100$. Moreover, this is the smallest value of $N$ for which $\lceil N/50\rceil\ge 100$.

Comment: Don't solve by back substitution ...!! i wan't explanation for the answer :)@pi66

Comment: Well, if $N=4950$ then $\lceil N/50\rceil=99$, and clearly if $N<4950$ then $\lceil N/50\rceil\le 99$. So $N=4951$ is the smallest value satisfying your inequality.